# What translation maps $ T'U'V'W' $ back to $ TUVW $?

Tags: geometry

I need help for my online school.

The translation $ (x,y) \mapsto (x + 3,y – 7) $ maps the quadrilateral $ TUVW $ to $ T'U'V'W' $. Which of the following translations maps $ T'U'V'W' $ back to $ TUVW $?
\begin{align*}
(x,y) & \mapsto (x + 3,y - 7). \\
(x,y) & \mapsto (x - 7,y + 3). \\
(x,y) & \mapsto (x + 7,y - 3). \\
(x,y) & \mapsto (x - 3,y + 7).
\end{align*}

I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The translation $ (x + a,y + b) $ has inverse $ (x - a,y - b) $ because
$$
(x - a,y - b) (x + a,y + b) = (x + a - a,y + b - b) = (x,y),
$$
which is the identity on $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $. The notation is that of C. Sidney.

Comment: typing error.... the penultimate bracket should be

Comment: (x + a -a , y + b -b)...apologies